# What templating language does helm use?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am new to kubernetes and helm.
I started using helm and I have the follwoing snippet:

```
{{- $image := printf "%s/%s:%s" $.Values.global.repository $.Values.global.images.xxx.image $.Values.global.images.xxx.tag -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: xxxx-test-ready
  labels:
    app: xxxxx-test
    app.kubernetes.io/name: xxxxx-test
    helm.sh/chart: authsvc
    release: {{ $.Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ $.Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ $.Release.Service }}
```

My issue is here:

```
  {{- $image := printf "%s/%s:%s" $.Values.global.repository $.Values.global.images.xxx.image $.Values.global.images.xxx.tag -}}
```

I think I understand what it does : basically it creates the image specification and add it to a var called image for later use case. however I do not feel comfortable with this templating language and I am not even sure if it is erlang or golang. What is the best starting point to get confident with this templating language? Should I learn golang?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best starting point is to read the official documentation: [The Chart Template Developer’s Guide](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#the-chart-template-developer-s-guide), which provides an introduction to Helm’s chart templates, with emphasis on the template language.

> While we talk about “Helm template language” as if it is Helm-specific, it is actually
>   a combination of the Go template language, some extra functions, and a
>   variety of wrappers to expose certain objects to the templates. Many
>   resources on Go templates may be helpful as you learn about
>   templating.
>
> Helm has over 60 available functions. Some of them are defined by the
>   [Go template](https://godoc.org/text/template) language itself. Most of the others are part of the
>   [Sprig template library](https://godoc.org/github.com/Masterminds/sprig).

Dig into the above Sprig and Go Template documentation to enhance your knowledge about chart templates.